# How do I get rid of fsp error on samba share?

Tags: samba

While I'm editing, moving, renaming files on my samba share, the deamon continue to spam the journal with this kind of errors. What's wrong?

```
smbd[2496813]: [2022/05/09 17:04:34.855036,  0] ../../source3/smbd/fd_handle.c:118(fsp_get_io_fd)
smbd[2496813]:   fsp_get_io_fd: fsp [<path/to/file>] is a path referencing fsp
```

Comment: It's somehow related to the fact that my samba share is a btrfs subvolume, I tried to share a subfolder and it's not spitting out those errors

Answer (score 2):

I do have exactly the same issue with Samba 4.16.1 on arch linux.
What I found by googling is something that might be related in terms of handling fsp_get_io_fd: https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14685

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).